# C# WCF - windows - publish

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have C# windows application -WCF with 2 startup projects. one is console application which calls   WCF Service. Now the Windows application will call the console application. I have set both console and windows as startup projects. I would like to publish the windows application. How can i make my both application to start at single exe?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Once the service starts in the console apps, call the win form inside the main of the console. Then hide the console which you can see the form.